# I missed these mistakes with database

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I missed these mistakes:

```
System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'initial catalog'.
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnectionStringBuilder.GetIndex(String keyword)
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnectionStringBuilder.set_Item(String keyword, Object value)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String connectionString)
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
   at Task5.Data.SqlRepository`1.GetTable(String where) in D:\Task5\Task5.Data\Repositories\SqlRepository.cs:line 96
   at Task5.Data.SqlRepository`1.Select() in D:\Task5\Task5.Data\Repositories\SqlRepository.cs:line 39
   at Task5.Data.Services.EntityDataService.CategoryList() in D:\Task5\Task5.Data\Services\EntityDataService.cs:line 32
   at Task5.Program.Step1() in D:\Task5\Task5\Program.cs:line 74
```

My code where error:

```
private List<TEntity> GetTable(string where = null)
{
    var query = $"select * from {GetTableName()} {where}";

    var dataTable = new DataTable();
    using(var sqlConnection = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCeDataAdapter sqlDA = new SqlCeDataAdapter(query, sqlConnection);
        sqlDA.Fill(dataTable);
    }

    var entityList = new List<TEntity>();
    foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
    {
        var entity = new TEntity();
        foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
        {
            var value = row[column.ColumnName];
            typeof(TEntity).GetProperty(column.ColumnName).SetValue(entity, value);
        }

        entityList.Add(entity);
    }

    return entityList;
 }
```

Comment: I really can't fathom what it is you're asking here.

Comment: `Keyword not supported: 'initial catalog'`  The error message seems clear.  Where is "initial catalog" in your project?  SQL CE does not support that configuration option.

Comment: @Amy no I have InstallDB.sql

Comment: @Amy 
It's not clear what I'm wrong with. If you know where the error is, tap your finger

Comment: @Amy 
Ok I'm dumb. And can you say what to delete and where?

Comment: @Amy connectionString="Data Source=.\\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=Task5;Integrated Security=True;" what can this be wrong?

Comment: `Keyword not supported: 'initial catalog'`  Do you see, in your connection string, the phrase "initial catalog"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Amy pointed out, the error message is pretty straightforward.  This looks like a problem with your connection string, as you are likely trying to use a SQL Server connection string with a SQL CE database.  I believe the format should be something like:

`Data Source=MyData.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;`

See [this link](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-compact/) for more details about SQL CE connection strings.

**Edit**

If you are in fact using a SQL database (Express or otherwise) then you are using the wrong library to connect to it.  You are using `SqlCeConnection` which does not support the SQL Express connection string.  You should use `SqlConnection` and `SqlDataAdapter`.

*Note: I edited this without testing at all*

```
private List<TEntity> GetTable(string where = null)
{
    var query = $"select * from {GetTableName()} {where}";

    var dataTable = new DataTable();
    using(var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlConnection);
        sqlDA.Fill(dataTable);
    }

    var entityList = new List<TEntity>();
    foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
    {
        var entity = new TEntity();
        foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
        {
            var value = row[column.ColumnName];
            typeof(TEntity).GetProperty(column.ColumnName).SetValue(entity, value);
        }

        entityList.Add(entity);
    }

    return entityList;
 }
```

Comment: No, database - Microsoft SQL Server Query File (.sql)

Comment: <add name="DEFAULT" connectionString="Data Source=.\\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=Task5;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

Comment: See above edit, if you're using SQL and not SQL CE then your code is wrong.  Please note, including these details in future questions will help users better respond to your questions and provide accurate solutions.